# Why can't I access the item in this Swift dictionary?

Tags: swift

```
var foo: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>[] = [["grapes": 10, "blueberries": "twelve"], ["carrots": "fifteen"]]

// Works
var bar = foo[0]["grapes"]! as Int // Works

var dict = foo[0]

// Compiler error
var grapesValue = dict["grapes"]! as Int
```

I create an array of `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` variables.

If I access the array item, then the dictionary item, it works fine. But if I separate them into variables, I can't. I get this error:

> Use 'as' to downcast to 'Int'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Use 'as' to downcast to 'Int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really strange!

A couple of workaround in this case would include:

`var grapesValue = dict["grapes"] as NSNumber`

-or-

`var grapesValue = dict["grapes"]?.integerValue`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is it a compiler bug or language defect but this is a workaround

```
 19> var grapesValue = dict["grapes"] as NSNumber as Int
grapesValue: Int = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Foundation imported? Swift sometimes starts making some assumptions if you do. Removing the import helps solve some of this. Start with the first line.

```
var foo: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>[] = [["grapes": 10, "blueberries": "twelve"], ["carrots": "fifteen"]]
```

Without Foundation, Swift chokes on this line. Swift Dictionaries do not conform to the AnyObject protocol because they are classes. If the foundation classes are available though, swift assumes you meant NSDictionary and uses that instead.

We can get it to work without Foundation by changing AnyObject to Any. Now we can use all of this code normally:

```
var bar = foo[0]["grapes"] as Int

var dict = foo[0] as Dictionary<String, Any>

var grapesValue = dict["grapes"] as Int
```

I added a cast on dict, and removed the ! after the subscripts. NSDictionary returns an implicitly unwrapped optional, but with a Dictionary, we know we're going to get something.

All of this code works with Foundation imported as well, but it was helpful to remove in order to find out what assumptions Swift was making and how to fix them.

You may want to take a look at this [article](http://drewag.me/posts/swift-s-weird-handling-of-basic-value-types-and-anyobject) that helped me out.

Edit: The reason you are getting that error on the cast is because an NSDictionary can only store AnyObjects, so it has to use NSNumber instead of Int. Swift also translates these back and forth if you have Foundation imported. Although in this case it couldn't figure out the last line for some reason. The workarounds suggested by Bryan and fqdn seem to be able to coerce Swift into understanding. This one also worked for me:

```
var dict = foo[0] as NSDictionary
var grapesValue = dict["grapes"] as Int
```